# Visual Studio Code suddenly lost autocomplete with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have been programming on Unity with VSCode for the past two months and had very few issues about it. But suddenly, it has stopped the autocomplete, even thought I tried several approaches that I found online.

I have all the extensions needed for the development (C# (1.22), Debugger for Unity(2.7.5), Unity Code Snippets (1.3.0), Unity Tools (1.2.3) and am currently using Unity 2019.3.8f1 on Windows 10.

I have already changed the External Script Editor to work with VSCode but with no luck. I have also tried to delete all `.csproj` files, to restart computer/internet, all with no luck either

It says on my output panel that it is installing C# dependencies, but it never ends downloading them.

What is the possible cause of this problem ? I have found that many people have this kind of error, but they are always when trying to use VSCode with Unity for their first time. In my case I have been using for a long time and it has suddenly stopped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try disabling newest C# addon and installing older [C# 1.21.12](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/download/v1.21.12/csharp-1.21.12.vsix).

More on that: https://forum.unity.com/threads/psa-if-your-vs-code-c-extension-stopped-working.841255/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# vscode extensions works by having the actual c# heavy lifting in a separate language server process "omnisharp.exe", and actual typescript extensions is mostly glue. So whenever c# extension gets updated, extensions manually downloads new version of omnisharp.exe.

As far as I know, all language services are turned off while new omnisharp.exe is downloading. Why your download is failing, I can't tell you really without more info, it could be something on your end.

I suggest you first try to uninstall/install c# extensions, as that may help if extension folder got corrupted in any way. If that doesn't help, try setting "omnisharp.path" vscode settings to "1.35.2" or "1.35.1" or similar, to manually target version.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! But i had to do some changes too in regards to this:                           1) I uninstalled C# extension from VSCode and reinstalled it, made native c# autocomplete to work again, but not unity methods;                                                                                                 2) i uninstalled all unity extensions and then installed then again. After this, i went into unity and opened the script from there, making autocomplete work again